# ID's in dynamic list of buttons

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a list of buttons:

```
<button [id]="'matMenuButton' + i" *ngFor="let item of matMenuItems; let i of index;" > {{item}} </button>
```

I am trying to get dynamic ids like matMenuButton1, matMenuButton2, etc. but this not work.

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Change the html code to this

```
<button
  id="matMenuButton_{{i}}"
  *ngFor="let item of matMenuItems; let i = index;"
>
  {{item}}
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The local variable assignment to `index` must either be of form `let i=index` or `let index as i` and CANNOT be `let i of index`.
2. You need to add 1 to `i` for the list to 1, 2, 3... since `index` starts from 0.

#### Option 1: Binding

```html
<button 
  [id]="'matMenuButton' + (i+1)" 
  *ngFor="let item of matMenuItems; let i=index;"
> 
  {{item}} 
</button>
```

#### Option 2: Interpolation

You could also use interpolation `{{ }}` instead of binding `[]`.

```html
<button 
  id="matMenuButton{{i+1}}" 
  *ngFor="let item of matMenuItems; let i=index;"
> 
  {{item}} 
</button>
```

But TBH, if you're doing things "the Angular way" there wouldn't be a need for DOM `id`s. Perhaps there are other ways to do what you're attempting if you could provide more information about what you wish to do with the `id`s after it's assignment.